# How to overcome with this aberrant nature of debugger in visual studio

Tags: asp.net

in debug mode I am facing this problem and debug aberrantly  stops with this error, and finally when i keep doing F10 i face this file name in brows "ExtenderControlBase".

```
AjacControlToolKit.DLL!AjaxControlToolKit.TollKitScriptManager.OnLoad(Syste.Events.args) line177

Locating source for 'C:\Users\Stephen\Documents\Repos\Superexpert\AjaxControlToolkit\Server\AjaxControlToolkit\ToolkitScriptManager\ToolkitScriptManager.cs'. Checksum: MD5 {d9 23 62 78 1a b1 5e b3 94 86 f5 56 7c ea 3f 47}
The file 'C:\Users\Stephen\Documents\Repos\Superexpert\AjaxControlToolkit\Server\AjaxControlToolkit\ToolkitScriptManager\ToolkitScriptManager.cs' does not exist.
Looking in script documents for 'C:\Users\Stephen\Documents\Repos\Superexpert\AjaxControlToolkit\Server\AjaxControlToolkit\ToolkitScriptManager\ToolkitScriptManager.cs'...
Looking in the projects for 'C:\Users\Stephen\Documents\Repos\Superexpert\AjaxControlToolkit\Server\AjaxControlToolkit\ToolkitScriptManager\ToolkitScriptManager.cs'.
The file was not found in a project.
Looking in directory 'g:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\crt\src\'...
Looking in directory 'g:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\src\mfc\'...
Looking in directory 'g:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\src\atl\'...
Looking in directory 'g:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\include\'...
The debug source files settings for the active solution indicate that the debugger will not ask the user to find the file: C:\Users\Stephen\Documents\Repos\Superexpert\AjaxControlToolkit\Server\AjaxControlToolkit\ToolkitScriptManager\ToolkitScriptManager.cs.
The debugger could not locate the source file 'C:\Users\Stephen\Documents\Repos\Superexpert\AjaxControlToolkit\Server\AjaxControlToolkit\ToolkitScriptManager\ToolkitScriptManager.cs'.
```

Comment: I'm wondering exactly when this error appears? If you're trying to step into code in the AjaxControlToolKit, you're not going to be able to debug it unless you locate the source for that library.